# Failed to Create react-project Using Create-React-app

Tags: reactjs

I've Installed Create-react-app globally in my system but I'm unable to create react projects with it.I have followed similar issues on stackoverflow but none of them have a solution. 
My Node version: 12.16.2
My NPM version : 6.14.4
[image]

Please help me to move on with this.

Comment: please try " npx create-react-app yourAppName "

Comment: I have tried npx but it gives the same error . Infact I have tried clearing  cache , switching registry uninstalling and re-installing node but had no luck.

Comment: Add your debug logs here

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not aware of Debug logs.Would you please elaborate.

Comment: Fixed it. clearing npm cache manually going to the npm cache folder worked for me!.

Comment: However ,I would still want to know about Debug Logs!